# shinydashboard, logo locally from folder

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a newly occured problem, if the logo that I want to be displayed on the dashboard is in the folder (working directory is correctly set)   it is not shown anymore, I tried all possible combinations (I put the logo.jpg in the www, I put it directly in the same folder as the "app.R", wrote `tags$img(src = 'www/logo.jpg')` and one without the `www/`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(){

dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(
title = "Demo",
tags$li(class = "dropdown",
        tags$a(href = 'https://google.com',
               tags$img(src = 'logo.jpg', height= 50,width= 50, align = "right")
        )
 ),
  dropdownMenuOutput('messageMenu')
 ),
 dashboardSidebar( sidebarMenu(id="side", menuItem("Option1", tabName="op1"),

                            menuItem("Option2", tabName="op2"), 
menuItem("Option3", tabName="op3"))
),


body=dashboardBody())
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

however adding the logo as an external link works perfectly, e.g.

```
tags$img(src = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', height= 50,width= 50, align = "right")
```

(up until few weeks having the logo saved in the local folder `www/` also displayed it when I started the app locally)
was there any change recently in `shinydashboard`, or does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: I put a logo.jpg file in `www` directory where I ran your app without any edits and the logo showed up as expected, in the right hand corder, with the specified dimensions. It seems like something changed in your local environment, but it's not related to `shinydashboard`.

Comment: @guasi: Thank you so much for taking the time to look into this. may I ask which version of R and R-Studio you use? is there maybe any way where I could find out where this problem stems from? I even tried to give the full local path in the tags$img(src="...)... but unfortunately this also does not work

Comment: I'm running R version 4.2.0, R Studio 2022.02.3 Build 492, shiny_1.7.1, shinydashboard_0.7.2. I'm on a Mac.  I'm not very knowledgeable of how R interprets paths, but if I were you, I would start with the basics, restarting R studio and doing a little test with a single page in a separate directory with a fresh environment. If it works, then it's not related to packages or R Studio but some condition on the environment of the app with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix for the `www` folder is "/". Please see the details section [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/resourcePaths.html).

A working example:

```
imgName = "logo.png"

if(!dir.exists("www")){
  dir.create("www")
}

png(file = paste0("www/", imgName), bg = "lightgreen")
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, imgName, cex = 10, col = "black")
dev.off()

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function() {
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Demo",
      tags$li(class = "dropdown",
              tags$a(
                href = 'https://google.com',
                tags$img(
                  src = '/logo.png',
                  height = "50px",
                  width = "50px"
                ),
                style = "padding: 0;"
              ))
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
      id = "side",
      menuItem("Option1", tabName = "op1"),
      menuItem("Option2", tabName = "op2"),
      menuItem("Option3", tabName = "op3")
    )),
    body = dashboardBody()
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

As an alternative you can use `addResourcePath` to make any other folders available to the webserver:

```
imgName = "logo.png"

if(!dir.exists("images")){
  dir.create("images")
}

addResourcePath(prefix = "img", directoryPath = "images")

png(file = paste0("images/", imgName), bg = "lightgreen")
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, imgName, cex = 10, col = "black")
dev.off()

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function() {
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Demo",
      tags$li(class = "dropdown",
              tags$a(
                href = 'https://google.com',
                tags$img(
                  src = 'img/logo.png',
                  height = "50px",
                  width = "50px"
                ),
                style = "padding: 0;"
              ))
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
      id = "side",
      menuItem("Option1", tabName = "op1"),
      menuItem("Option2", tabName = "op2"),
      menuItem("Option3", tabName = "op3")
    )),
    body = dashboardBody()
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: the same can be done with `jpeg()` or better svg images.

Comment: thank you so so much, with the second solution it is finally working. Thanks again